# On reverse engineering an udp protocol to control a drone

Tags: python, disassemblers, apk, protocol, wireshark

My goal is to control my drone with my raspberry pi using python and not the app that is being delivered together with it.

- First I connected the app to the drone, flew and used aircrack-ng to get the pcap.
- I looked at it in wireshark and could not make sense of it.
- I presume it to be unencrypted UDP though.
- So I decompiled the java apk with APK Studio and looked at the source code.
- I looked for a random button in an xml to find the corresponding method in a java file.
- It did not exist.

There are some small files.

Which approach do you suggest for reverse engineering?

Comment: For decompiling the Android app I would use Jadx. Try to identify where the UDP packets  are sent and then trace back the calls where the packets are generated. As you have a running set-up you may use Frida on certain methods you have identified via Jadx and hook them to see what parameters they are called with at run-time.

Comment: Feel free to try it with the A20 app: https://m.apkpure.com/de/potensic/com.udirc.Potensic Using APK Studio, which is a gui for jadx, I wasn't able to extract the methods that referred to the buttons. If you are more successful, I'd appreciate the steps you took, not necessarily the result. PS: Is Frida a stacktracer, ie it points out the command route?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an android app, you may use network debuggers such as

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture

this also supports UDP

This might be easier to use/retrieve your data.

I used this myself to gain independent access to my Iot devices.

Be aware:
Some apps have their own client certificates pinned in their apps for authorization purposes.
So this method might not work.
You'd need to find a way to extract the client certificate and use it to get the traffic data.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a drone, it's probably MAVLink. Check that first. https://mavlink.io/en/guide/serialization.html